# SoundCloud API - how to play private sound with HTML5 <audio> tag

Tags: soundcloud

I would like to play sound with HTML5  tag.

The sourcecode is shown as below:

```
  SC.get("/tracks/153068147", {}, function(sound, error) {
    $('#player').attr('src', sound.stream_url + '?client_id=' + client_id);
  });
```

When I set the sound to be public, it works well. But when I set it to be private, it does not work. What is the problem?

By the way, I also authenticated my APP with SC.connect before I play it. And the sound is also uploaded with my SoundCloud account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace http to https and add user_auth_token in the url
so:

```
`$('#player').attr('src', sound.stream_url.replace('http:','https:') + '?client_id=' + client_id+'&oauth_token=' + oAuthToken);`
```

Comment: Yes, I could understand user_auth_token might be helpful for private track. But how can I get the token with JS SDK API.

Comment: OK, I got it by SC.accessToken(), Thx~